# How can I get accurate results from ElasticSearch and Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a problem to solve in graphing from ElasticSearch / Kibana.  For the sake of argument, I have a turnstile and I need a 100% accurate count of the number of unique people who've passed through the turnstile.  If Fred and Joe go through then the count is 2 - but if Fred and Joe and Joe go through (because Joe left and came in again) then the count is still two.  Rather than people, I'm dealing with files - and rather than names I'm using UUIDs but the principle is the same.

We've tried using Cardinality Aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) but that doesn't work.  Even with tuning it only approaches 100% accuracy, and the possibility of a 100% accurate result decreases as the number of data points goes up.  The number of data points that I'm looking at is in the tens, and possibly hundreds, of millions.

I understand that there's a performance / accuracy tradeoff - I can live with slow, but I can't live with inaccurate.

What would be the correct function - or correct way - of getting a 100% accurate count of unique names?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround of [doing a complete terms aggregation and then running a `scripted_metric` on that](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15876#issuecomment-274449889), but this is really really expensive.

```
{
"byFullListScripting": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "groupId",
    "shard_size": Integer.MAX_VALUE,
    "size": Integer.MAX_VALUE
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cntScripting": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "map_script": "targetId='u'+doc['cntTargetId']; if (_agg[targetId] == null) { _agg[targetId] = 1}",
        "reduce_script": "map=[:]; for (a in _aggs){ map.putAll(a) }; return map.size()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```